# How to change speed when crouching?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the player slower when he moves while crouching.

```cs
private float moveSpeed = 5f;
private float crouchSpeed = 0.2f;
private float runSpeed = 8.5f;    
private void PlayerMovement() 
{
    move = controls.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    movement = (move.y * transform.forward) + (move.x * transform.right);
    controller.Move(movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    
    if (isRunning)
    {
        run = controls.Player.Run.ReadValue<float>();
        Vector3 running = (move.y * transform.forward) + (move.x * transform.right);
        controller.Move(running * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (crouching)
    {
        isRunning = false;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, crouchYScale, transform.localScale.z);
        movement = (move.y * transform.forward) + (move.x * transform.right);
        controller.Move(movement * crouchSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
                
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, startYScale, transform.localScale.z);
        movement = (move.y * transform.forward) + (move.x * transform.right);
        controller.Move(movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

However, it is still the same speed as walking speed even when the player crouches. Why is that?

Comment: Add a `Debug.Log` inside your `if (crouching)` block and mention if the code inside that `if` statement is read.\

Comment: yes, it works. I tried printing the CrouchSpeed and when the user is crouching I can see it printing the speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to set speed is to delete duplications of same method. In this way you can define a temporary speed variable and pass it through different conditions to finally determine the main speed. In this method, you no longer need to redefine `Character.Move` and the problem will be solved.

```cs
var currentSpeed = moveSpeed;
if (isRunning)
{
    currentSpeed = runSpeed;
    run = controls.Player.Run.ReadValue<float>();
}
if (crouching)
{
    currentSpeed = crouchSpeed;
    isRunning = false;
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, crouchYScale, transform.localScale.z);
}
else // if move
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, startYScale, transform.localScale.z);
}
controller.Move(movement * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime); // without duplication and select true speed in last
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void PlayerMovement()
    {
        // stuff
        controller.Move(movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // stuff
        if (crouching)
        {
            // stuff
            controller.Move(movement * crouchSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
```

you do normal movement, then you ALSO do movement based on your run/crouch state.

Consider instead setting a currentSpeed equal to your walk speed, go through your cases and set the currentSpeed as appropriate, and then only have one place where you actually .Move(), after your speed is set.